# Why is the AWS S3 request failing, due to a CORS error, only in some instances?

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, cors

The browser (using [react-pdf-viewer](https://react-pdf-viewer.dev/examples/view-documents-from-remote-servers/)) makes a GET request to AWS S3 to fetch a pdf document.

```
GET /63...
Host: ..s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/111.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Referer: https://.../
Origin: https://...
Connection: keep-alive
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
```

This request is successful in most cases and returns a document. However, some users of the application have reported that this request was unsuccessful with the CORS header `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing (Statuscode 307)` error.

I failed to reproduce the error on Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Edge and Postman.

Our CORS settings on S3 also seems correct configured:

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "HEAD",
            "GET",
            "PUT",
            "POST",
            "DELETE"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": [
            "ETag"
        ]
    }
]
```

What could be the possible issue for this inconsistency and its resolution?

Answer (score 1):

**If this issue is occurring with only a few users then it might be the case that the CORS error is caused by some installed browser extensions on their machine or security settings of the browser that are blocking the request.**

Another possibility is even though your S3 CORS settings look correct, the error can be caused by a misconfiguration of the CORS settings on the server side. For example, if your S3 bucket is behind a CloudFront distribution, you may need to configure the CORS settings on both the S3 bucket and the CloudFront distribution.

You can try asking the affected users to try disabling their extensions or changing their security settings and see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: So after some digging, the issue was that the user was behind the organizations McAfee WebGateway (proxy firewall). 

Solution was to whitelist our AWS S3 bucket in McAfee WebGateway.

Comment: @Neha I just want to thank you so so so os so so so soso so much! :) as you said, my case was chrome extension.. I was looking for the solution over 3 months now I've fixed. Super thanks. Have a great day!